# d3v4 Twisted Pie chart conversion

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart

[image]

I have created a different type of pie chart - that relies on the segments being jarred than the colors

I am trying to refactor and upgrade a d3v3 version to 4. I am getting bugs though with paths and my pointers/labels had errors too.

I think I can streamline the data json to a simple array and take out the color value in the json later.

```
  var arcpaths = chart.selectAll("path")
    .data(data);

  arcpaths.enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d, i) {
      return d.machineType;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return d.color;
    })
    .transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  arcpaths.transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return d.color;
    })
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

  arcpaths.exit().transition()
    .ease("bounce")
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween)
    .remove();
```

--

version 3
https://jsfiddle.net/uv4t5692/

version 4 part 2 -- working 
https://jsfiddle.net/56avjbpc/1/

---

improved it - https://jsfiddle.net/56avjbpc/1/ -- thank you for your help -- is there a cleaner way of refactoring the input data -- the prepared data function etc.. this is old code - maybe some map could be used here and there?

Comment: Looks like you’re falling victim to a common issue people run into when porting from v3 to v4: selections now behave more immutable. When you make a change to the `arcpaths.enter()` selection, that does *not* modify the `arcpaths` update selection. You need to do something like `arcpaths = arcpaths.enter().append("path").merge(arcpaths)`. `selection.merge()` will combine the `enter` and update selections into one, which you can then assign back to your original selection.

Comment: Could you make the correct in a jsfiddle -- https://jsfiddle.net/f0brp9m7/1/

Comment: I have some other chart work -- with pie segments - I don't think I had to modify this part of the code with some merger -- the input json may be throwing it off -- I did some weird displacement of the segments to get that affect

Comment: ah my data input looks wrong -- https://jsfiddle.net/p08ur25j/1/

Comment: improved it - https://jsfiddle.net/56avjbpc/1/ -- thank you for your help -- is there a cleaner way of refactoring the input data -- the prepared data function etc.. this is old code - maybe some map could be used here and there?

Comment: I just looked through quickly, but you seem to be doing a lot of work yourself that d3 can do for you :) Take a look at [`d3.pie()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.7/README.md#pie) to figure out start and end angles for each data point, and [`arc.centroid()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.7/README.md#arc_centroid) to find the endpoint for your labels.

Comment: I think - its cause of the animation aspects it might look more busy - I will check out those functions later